# Button OnClick inner class error

Tags: java, android

Hello everyone so I have an app that counts the number of times you drank water by clicking on a glass. I wanted to add a reset count button, and I thought it would be as simple as setting the waterCount to 0 after the reset button was clicked. I am getting an error saying

Variable 'waterCount' is accessed from within a inner class, must be declared final.

I know what this means but I do not know how to fix this. Here is my code:

```
 private void updateWaterCount()
 {
    int waterCount = PreferenceUtilities.getWaterCount(this);
    resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            waterCount = 0; //error line
        }
    });
    mWaterCountDisplay.setText(waterCount+"");
 }
```

If you need to see anymore code I will be happy to provide it, thanks.

Comment: Any variable defined in a method and accessed by an anonymous inner class must be "effectively final" . the solution is either make it final which means you can't change the value or make it global then you can change the value of the variable.

Comment: yes thank you very much that makes quite a lot of sense

Comment: post your full activity class or fragment class , it will be helpful

Comment: Global, i.e., static is bad. It's enough to make it an instance variable, usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it not be better to declare your `int waterCount` as a global variable and have your functions increment and decrement accordingly?

Comment: No, it wouldn't, because there are no global variables in Java. Do you mean 'instance variable'?

Comment: Global, i.e., static is bad. It's enough to make it an instance variable, usually. Not a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Variable 'waterCount' is accessed from within a inner class, must be
>   declared final.

You should declare `waterCount` as `global` variable instead of `final`, because you need to update `waterCount` value. Using `final` it is not possible to update its value.

**Try this:**

```
int waterCount;

private void updateWaterCount()
{
    waterCount = PreferenceUtilities.getWaterCount(this);

    resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            waterCount = 0;
        }
    });
    mWaterCountDisplay.setText(waterCount+"");
}
```

Comment: yes this solution worked, but I already had figured this out though :) Thanks anyway for your clear solution

Comment: What is with all this insistence on using "global" variables? Besides that there really isn't such a thing in Java in the first place, global state is a well-known antipattern! Java's closest kin to global state is `static` state, which is to be avoided. Don't recommend global variables.

Comment: So, Lew, please enlighten us as to a better way to access a variable across multiple functions. I am not fluent in Java.